# getting error on vector<unique_ptr<X>> v

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, unique-ptr

I´m quiet new on C++ and currently learning to understand smart pointers.Therefore  I`m currently working on a little console-program for inserting,searching and deleting songs ... for learning purposes to get used to the stuff =)

Here is my code:

Song.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Song
{

public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Song> pSong;

public:
    Song();
    ~Song();
    void setTitle(std::string title);
    void setArtist(std::string artist);
    void checkSong(std::string item, int iterator);
    void get();

private:
    std::string _title;
    std::string _artist;
};
```

Song.cpp

```
#include "Song.hpp"
#include <iostream>



Song::Song()
{
}


Song::~Song()
{
}

void Song::setTitle(std::string title)
{
    _title = title;
}

void Song::setArtist(std::string artist)
{
    _artist = artist;
}

void Song::checkSong(std::string item, int iterator)
{
    if (_artist == item || _title == item)
    {
        std::cout << "Item found on Slot: " << iterator << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "No item found!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void Song::get()
{
    std::cout << _artist << " - " << _title << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include "Song.hpp"

//prototype
void IntVector();
void SongVector();
Song* setSong(std::string title, std::string artist);
void find(std::string item, std::vector<Song::pSong> v);


std::vector<Song::pSong> SongList;

int main()
{
    int k;
    SongVector();
    std::cin >> k;
    return 0;
}

void IntVector()
{
    // Create Vector
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;

    // Create a few unique_ptr<int> instances and fill them with ints
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(30)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(600)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(200)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(20)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(200)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(160)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(4)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(5)));
    v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(315)));


    // define vector<int> for storing values of the unique_ptr
    std::vector<int> intList;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        // get memory-adress of each element
        auto result = v[i].get();
        // store value of result-pointer in Vector
        intList.push_back(*result);
        std::cout << *result << std::endl;
    }

    // Sort int of new Vector
    std::sort(intList.begin(), intList.end());

    // Loop through intList and cout
    for (int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << intList[i] << std::endl;
    }

}

void SongVector()
{

    Song* first = setSong("Afroki","Steve Aoki");
    Song* secound = setSong("Hype", "Steve Aoki");
    Song* third = setSong("Madness", "Steve Aoki");
    Song* fourth = setSong("Cake Face", "Steve Aoki");
    SongList.push_back(Song::pSong(first));
    SongList.push_back(Song::pSong(secound));
    SongList.push_back(Song::pSong(third));
    SongList.push_back(Song::pSong(fourth));

    for (const auto& song : SongList)
    {
        song->get();
    }

    find("Madness", SongList);
}

Song* setSong(std::string title, std::string artist)
{
    Song* song = nullptr;
    song = new Song;
    song->setArtist(artist);
    song->setTitle(title);
    return song;
}


void find(std::string item, std::vector<Song::pSong> v)
{

    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& song : v)
    {
        song->checkSong(item,i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I got following error:

```
std::unique_ptr<Song,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Song
1>          ]
```

I found out, that this error only occurs, when calling my find(...)-method, so I´m guessing that somewhere in there is my mistake, but I just can`t find out, what I`ve done wrong. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you would get more answers if you boiled your program down to the minimal number of lines of code that still exhibit the problem. This would also, possibly, make you realize what the problem is.

Comment: The specific function is the copy constructor of `unique_ptr`. That function is deleted to make sure the pointer **is** unique. So you can't copy the pointer, or a vector containing such pointers.

Comment: Shachar Shemesh Sry, but thought it`s better to post the whole thing, instead of little pieces. Will cut my code in future questions ... thx for the advice, also thy Bo Persson ... it totally makes sence, when rethinking =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` provide unique ownership (hense the name) which means beside other you cannot copy instance of `std::unique_ptr` - which would mean shared ownership. When you passing `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<whatever>>` by value you creating a copy of vector instance, which tries to copy each element. So simplest solution would be to pass `std::vector` instance by const reference (as you do not have intention to modify vector):

```
void find( const std::string &item, const std::vector<Song::pSong>& v);
```

beside fixing your problem passing by (const) reference is more efficient for non trivial objects, so you can also use it for `std::string`

in your `intVector()` function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        // get memory-adress of each element
        auto result = v[i].get();
        // store value of result-pointer in Vector
        intList.push_back(*result);           
        std::cout << *result << std::endl;
     }
```

you do not really need to get raw pointer, just use `std::unique_ptr` itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    // get smart pointer for each element
    const auto &result = v[i];
    // store value of result-pointer in Vector
    intList.push_back(*result);
    std::cout << *result << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void find(std::string item, std::vector<Song::pSong> v)
```

You need to pass vectors by reference. Add &.

```
void find(std::string item, std::vector<Song::pSong>& v)
```

Don't forget to also change the prototype of the function.